# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to predict using SVM but I receive the error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

when executing line `text_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)` of my code. How to fix this and get the probability that my prediction is correct using SVM?

I am predicting the first column (gold) of my input file based on the values of the remaining columns. My input file `dataExtended.txt`is under the form:

```
   gold,T-x-T,T-x-N,T-x-U,T-x-NT,T-x-UT,T-x-UN,T-x-UNT,N-x-T,N-x-N,N-x-U,N-x-NT,N-x-UT,N-x-UN,N-x-UNT,U-x-T,U-x-N,U-x-U,U-x-NT,U-x-UT,U-x-UN,U-x-UNT,NT-x-T,NT-x-N,NT-x-U,NT-x-NT,NT-x-UT,NT-x-UN,NT-x-UNT,UT-x-T,UT-x-N,UT-x-U,UT-x-NT,UT-x-UT,UT-x-UN,UT-x-UNT,UN-x-T,UN-x-N,UN-x-U,UN-x-NT,UN-x-UT,UN-x-UN,UN-x-UNT,UNT-x-T,UNT-x-N,UNT-x-U,UNT-x-NT,UNT-x-UT,UNT-x-UN,UNT-x-UNT,T-T-x,T-N-x,T-U-x,T-NT-x,T-UT-x,T-UN-x,T-UNT-x,N-T-x,N-N-x,N-U-x,N-NT-x,N-UT-x,N-UN-x,N-UNT-x,U-T-x,U-N-x,U-U-x,U-NT-x,U-UT-x,U-UN-x,U-UNT-x,NT-T-x,NT-N-x,NT-U-x,NT-NT-x,NT-UT-x,NT-UN-x,NT-UNT-x,UT-T-x,UT-N-x,UT-U-x,UT-NT-x,UT-UT-x,UT-UN-x,UT-UNT-x,UN-T-x,UN-N-x,UN-U-x,UN-NT-x,UN-UT-x,UN-UN-x,UN-UNT-x,UNT-T-x,UNT-N-x,UNT-U-x,UNT-NT-x,UNT-UT-x,UNT-UN-x,UNT-UNT-x,x-T-T,x-T-N,x-T-U,x-T-NT,x-T-UT,x-T-UN,x-T-UNT,x-N-T,x-N-N,x-N-U,x-N-NT,x-N-UT,x-N-UN,x-N-UNT,x-U-T,x-U-N,x-U-U,x-U-NT,x-U-UT,x-U-UN,x-U-UNT,x-NT-T,x-NT-N,x-NT-U,x-NT-NT,x-NT-UT,x-NT-UN,x-NT-UNT,x-UT-T,x-UT-N,x-UT-U,x-UT-NT,x-UT-UT,x-UT-UN,x-UT-UNT,x-UN-T,x-UN-N,x-UN-U,x-UN-NT,x-UN-UT,x-UN-UN,x-UN-UNT,x-UNT-T,x-UNT-N,x-UNT-U,x-UNT-NT,x-UNT-UT,x-UNT-UN,x-UNT-UNT,callersAtLeast1T,CalleesAtLeast1T,callersAllT,calleesAllT,CallersAtLeast1N,CalleesAtLeast1N,CallersAllN,CalleesAllN,childrenAtLeast1T,parentsAtLeast1T,childrenAtLeast1N,parentsAtLeast1N,childrenAllT,parentsAllT,childrenAllN,ParentsAllN,ParametersatLeast1T,FieldMethodsAtLeast1T,ReturnTypeAtLeast1T,ParametersAtLeast1N,FieldMethodsAtLeast1N,ReturnTypeN,ParametersAllT,FieldMethodsAllT,ParametersAllN,FieldMethodsAllN,ClassGoldN,ClassGoldT,Inner,Leaf,Root,Isolated,EmptyCallers,EmptyCallees,EmptyCallersCallers,EmptyCalleesCallees,Program,Requirement,MethodID
T,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,1,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,2,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,3,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,4,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,5,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,6,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,7,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,8,1
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,1,3
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,2,3
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,3,3
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,4,3
N,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,chess,5,3
```

Here is my full reproducible code:

```
# Make Predictions with Naive Bayes On The Iris Dataset
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split 
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline



data = pd.read_csv( 'dataExtended.txt', sep= ',') 
row_count, column_count = data.shape

    # Printing the dataswet shape 
print ("Dataset Length: ", len(data)) 
print ("Dataset Shape: ", data.shape) 
print("Number of columns ", column_count)

    # Printing the dataset obseravtions 
print ("Dataset: ",data.head()) 
data['gold'] = data['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes
data['Program'] = data['Program'].astype('category').cat.codes
    # Building Phase Separating the target variable 
X = data.values[:, 1:column_count] 
Y = data.values[:, 0] 

    # Splitting the dataset into train and test 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( 
X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100) 
    #Create a svm Classifier
svclassifier = svm.LinearSVC()

print('Before fitting')
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = svclassifier.predict(X_test)


text_clf = Pipeline([('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer()),('clf',LinearSVC())])
text_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Traceback leading to error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-8e85a0a9f81c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/mouna/ownCloud/Mouna Hammoudi/dumps/Python/Paper4SVM.py', wdir='C:/Users/mouna/ownCloud/Mouna Hammoudi/dumps/Python')

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/mouna/ownCloud/Mouna Hammoudi/dumps/Python/Paper4SVM.py", line 53, in <module>
    text_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 362, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1381, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 869, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)

  File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 232, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
```

Comment: Large part of code is irrelevant to the issue (hence unhelpful clutter), including a whole bunch of `print` statements. But why on earth would you want to apply TF-IDF on *numeric* data?

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the *full traceback* leading up to the error (everything after `Traceback (most recent call last):` as this helps localize where the error is coming from).  Please (almost) always do this when posting errors from Python code, especially if it involves non-trivial libraries.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the probability that each prediction is correct and TF-IDF seems to be the only way to do so when using SVM. without getting errors \

Comment: @desertnaut is right: Tfidfvectorizer expects strings (preferably - words), so it's complaining that it can't lowercase your values, because your values are numeric.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem more simply by running, using your input file, `data = pd.read_csv(filename); X, Y = data.values[:, 1:], data.values[:, 0]; tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(); tfidf.fit(X, Y)`.  I'm not really sure what you're expecting this to do because the columns in `X` do not contain strings, and [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit) read in this case the inputs (`X` in this case) should be an iterable of strings, but you're passing it arbitrary numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** use TF-IDF-related methods for numeric data; the method is exclusively for use with **text** data, hence it uses methods such as `.tolower()`, which are by default applicable to strings, hence the error. This is already apparent from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit):

> `fit`*(self, raw_documents, y=None)*
>
> Learn vocabulary and idf from training set.
>
> Parameters
>
> **raw_documents: *iterable***
>
> An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.

I am afraid that your rationale, as explained in the comments:

> I'm just trying to get the probability that each prediction is correct and TF-IDF seems to be the only way to do so when using SVM

is extremely weak. For starters, there is no such thing as "*the probability that each prediction is correct*" - I take it that you mean *probabilistic predictions*, in contrast to hard class predictions (see [Predict classes or class probabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367755/predict-classes-or-class-probabilities/51423325#51423325))

To get to the point of your actual requirement: in contrast to `LinearSVC`, which you are using here, `SVC` does indeed provide a `predict_proba` method, which should do the job (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba) and the instructions therein). Notice that LinearSVC is **not** actually an SVM - see answer in [Under what parameters are SVC and LinearSVC in scikit-learn equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843981/under-what-parameters-are-svc-and-linearsvc-in-scikit-learn-equivalent/33844092#33844092) for details.

In short, forget about TF-IDF and switch to SVC instead of LinearSVC.