# How to get the support vectors when using LinearSVC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using GridSearchCV and would like to save the support vectors as follows:

```
np.save("support_vectors.npy", gs_cv.best_estimator_.named_steps['svm'].support_vectors_)
```

But I get this error:

```
  File "./improved_grid_search.py", line 500, in <module>
    np.save("support_vectors.npy", gs_cv.best_estimator_.named_steps['svm'].support_vectors_)
AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'support_vectors_'
```

I checked and indeed LinearSVC doesn't seem to have this attribute. Where then are they saved?

I am using the following Pipe:

```
search_spaces = []
if ovr:
        if 'linear' in kernel_lst:
            search_spaces.append({'svm': [OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())], # optmized version of linear
                                  'svm__estimator__C': c})
        if 'poly' in kernel_lst:
            search_spaces.append({'svm': [OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='poly', cache_size=cache_size))],
                                  'svm__estimator__degree': degree,
                                  'svm__estimator__C': c})
        if 'rbf' in kernel_lst:
            search_spaces.append({'svm': [OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf', cache_size=cache_size))],
                                  'svm__estimator__gamma': gamma,
                                  'svm__estimator__C': c})
else:
        if 'linear' in kernel_lst:
            search_spaces.append({'svm': [LinearSVC()], # optmized version of linear
                                  'svm__C': c})
        if 'poly' in kernel_lst:
            search_spaces.append({'svm': [SVC(kernel='poly', cache_size=cache_size)],
                                  'svm__degree': degree,
                                  'svm__C': c})
        if 'rbf' in kernel_lst:
            search_spaces.append({'svm': [SVC(kernel='rbf', cache_size=cache_size)],
                                  'svm__gamma': gamma,
                                  'svm__C': c})

svm_pipe = Pipeline([('svm', DummyClassifier())])
```

And grid search is done this way:

```
grid_cv_object = GridSearchCV(
        estimator = svm_pipe,
        param_grid = search_spaces,
        cv = cv_splits,
        scoring = make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef), # a callable returning single value, binary and multiclass labels are supported
        n_jobs = -1, # use all processors
        verbose = 10,
        refit = refit,
        return_train_score = True
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinearSVC` optimizes a linear model (like `LogisticRegression` or `Lasso`) with a complexity penalty via some gradient-based method, without regard for support vectors. I'm afraid only `SVC` and `NuSVC` provide `support_vectors_`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already discovered yourself, `LinearSVC` does not have a `support_vectors_` attribute, only `coef_` and `intercept_` ones.

However, according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html), `LinearSVC` is:

> Similar to SVC with parameter kernel=’linear’, but implemented in terms of liblinear rather than libsvm, so it has more flexibility in the choice of penalties and loss functions and should scale better to large numbers of samples.

So, if you don't have performance issues, you can end up with your desired `support_vectors_` simply by replacing `LinearSVC()` with the largely equivalent `SVC(kernel='linear')`.

For more details, see [Under what parameters are SVC and LinearSVC in scikit-learn equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843981/under-what-parameters-are-svc-and-linearsvc-in-scikit-learn-equivalent) (tl;dr: `LinearSVC` is actually **not** a linear SVM).